# I don't know how to make my menu loop out of its choice in C#

Tags: c#, function, loops, menu

I am very new to C#, in fact, I have never coded before 4 months ago. That being said, I have to make a menu but I can't seem to be able to make it jump out of the loop when it is done doing one choice. For example, if the user answers all the questions being asked on the first choice, I want it to get out of the first choice and show the user all the other choices. Better example is below, (this is in C#):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 6");

Console.WriteLine("1: Areas of Rectangles");
Console.WriteLine("2: Biggest Number");
Console.WriteLine("3: Valid Points");
Console.WriteLine("4: Dollar Game");
Console.WriteLine("5: Oldest Person");
Console.WriteLine("6: Hi Lo Game");
Console.WriteLine("7: Quit Menu");

int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
do
{
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            Areas_Of_Rectangles();
            break;
        case 2:
            Biggest_Number();
            break;
        case 3:
            Valid_Points();
            break;
        case 4:
            Dollar_Game();
            break;
        case 5:
            Oldest_Person();
            break;
        case 6:
            Hi_Lo_Game();
            break;

        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice))
        {
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\"" + choice + "\"" + "is not a number");
    }
}
while (choice != 7);

static void Areas_Of_Rectangles()
{
    //=======================================================================================
    //Ask the user for the lenght and width of two rectangles
    //=======================================================================================
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the lenght of the first rectangle");
    int lenght1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the width of the first rectangle");
    int width1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int rec1 = lenght1 * width1;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the length of the second rectangle");
    int lenght2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the width of the second rectangle");
    int width2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int rec2 = lenght2 * width2;
    //==========================================================================================
    //Formulas to tell the user which rectangle has a greater area of if it has the same area
    //==========================================================================================

if (rec1 > rec2)
{
    Console.Write("Your first rectangle is bigger and has an area of " + rec1);
}
if (rec2 > rec1)
{
    Console.Write("Your second rectangle is bigger and has an area of " + rec2);
}
if (rec1 == rec2)
{
    Console.Write("Both your rectangles have an area of " + rec1);
}
```

Comment: That's because the choice is made before the loop. You need to reorder your code a bit. But you also have to add the code that will reduce the menu down to options not yet selected etc.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I will try that, thanks but how would i go about reducing my menu into options not yet selected?

Comment: You'd want to put them in some sort of collection (array, list, etc) and remove them as they're chosen. Keep in mind that your switch depends on the option number.